# Entity Framework - ASP MVC Models - Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have some Models in my app like so:

```
public class Enquiry
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Enquiry Type:")]
    public virtual int EnquiryTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual EnquiryType EnquiryType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DeliveryType> DeliveryTypes { get; set; }

}

public class EnquiryType
{
    [Key]
    public int EnquiryTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enquiry Type:")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string EnquiryTypeName { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryType
{
    [Key]
    public int DeliveryTypeID { get; set; }
    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryName{ get; set; }
}
```

So the jist of it is. I have an Enquiry, each Enquiry has a Type of Enquiry (Sales, General, Technical etc..) so this is a One-to-One relationship. Each Enquiry can then have multiple DeliveryTypes attached to it, so its a One-to-Many relationship.

My question is, have I set this up correctly with my models above? Am I missing something? Do I have virtual's in the wrong place/not set up correctly? Do I need `EnquiryID` to be in my DeliveryType model?

Comment: Do you have any problems with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need EnquiryID on the DeliveryType model.  But, the EnquiryTypeID on the Enquiry should not be virtual. I would set it up like this:

```
public class Enquiry
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Enquiry Type:")]
    public int EnquiryTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual EnquiryType EnquiryType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeliveryType> DeliveryTypes { get; set; }

}

public class EnquiryType
{
    [Key]
    public int EnquiryTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enquiry Type:")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string EnquiryTypeName { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryType
{
    [Key]
    public int DeliveryTypeID { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Out of curiosity, why would I remove the `EnquiryID` from `DeliveryType`. How would the relationship then be set up if `DeliveryType` has no idea which Enquiry it is attached too?

Comment: I guess I'm confused about how you are using DeliveryTypes.  Can a single DeliveryType be associated with many Enquiries, or will each DeliveryType only belong to a single Enquiry?  If the latter is true, then you are correct - you will need to add EnquiryId to the properties of DeliveryType.

Comment: Yeah that latter is true, sorry for the confusion! Thanks for the answer!